# only solution to wave equation under certain restriction?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

Suppose $u_1, u_2: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are two solutions to the wave equation
\begin{equation}
\partial_t^2u_i = \partial_x^2u_i
\end{equation}
obeying the restriction
$\partial_x \left(u_1^2 + u_2^2\right) = 0$.
Is it so that $u_1$ and $u_2$ must be of the form
\begin{equation}
u_1(x,t)=C_1\sin(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_1) + C_2\cos(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
u_2(x,t)=\pm \left( C_1\cos(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_1) - C_2\sin(kz)\sin(kt+\phi_2) \right)
\end{equation} 
EDIT: as is evident from Robert Israel's answer, $u_1(z,t)=0, u_2(z,t)=t$ is a counterexample. But of course it is not of the kind I'm looking for. So impose the extra constraint that $u_1$ and $u_2$ must be globally bounded, what about then?

Comment: Welcome to MSE what have you tried or what are your thoughts?

Comment: Ah my beloved MHD waves. :).

Comment: @gage if you check his profile he has a non trivial account on MO so I assume he understands the rules? No?

Comment: I assume you are trying to prove existence? Or the work done by the wave is constant? I have a background in nonlinear MHD and I haven't come across this formulation of conservation? Also do you have other initial conditions ?

Comment: No, in fact I come on this in the problem of nonlinear alfven waves in an ideal MHD setting where the velocity field is restricted to $\vec{v}=(v_x(z,t),v_y(z,t),0)$. If you check the $z$ component of the momentum equation and you let $u_1=B_x$, $u_2=B_y$ and take $z$ in stead of $x$ you come to this restriction, while also these components of the magn. field must satisfy the wave equation

Comment: Existence is then not my problem (because that question is already solved positively). Uniqueness is my problem.

Comment: I would modify the question with the full model as outlined in your comment..this will get my brain churning (thumbing over my thesis ;) )

Comment: I meant uniqueness instead of existence.

Comment: Ok :), can you tell me anything about existence of axisymmetric solutions to the ideal MHD equations with velocity field $\vec{v}=r\Omega(r,z,t) \hat{\phi}$ (cylindrical coordinates) with $\Omega$ nontrivially time-dependent? That question is also in my mind lately

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19674/discussion-between-chinny84-and-thibaut-demaerel).

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample: let $u_1(x,t) = 0$, $u_2(x,t) = t$.

Comment: In terms of MHD waves the solutions are periodic. With the waves being non degenerate (in general ideal .ie non resistive plasmas).